# #pragma managed(push, on) and #pragma managed(push, off) in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, pragma

What is the difference between `#pragma managed(push, off)` and `#pragma managed(push, on)`?

When we need to use `#pragma managed(push, on)` instead of `#pragma managed(push, off)`?

Comment: Stick it in your back pocket.  You'll get it out when you need it.  Could be a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's obvious - "off" turns managed code off, "on" - turns it on.
We use `#pragma managed(push, on)` when we need to save state and turn it on.
In common case, in header file, we don't know if managed code enabled, so we enable it:

```
#pragma once
#pragma managed(push, on)
public ref class Foo
{
    ...
};
#pragma managed(pop)
```